# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IntegrationSpec while running specs2 Tests in Intellij 14

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception, playframework-2.2, specs2

**What I did is:**

1. Install Intellij 14 (the same problem appears also with Intellij 13)
2. Install Scala 1.0 plugin for Intellij (supports Scala, SBT, SSP, HOCON and Play 2).
3. Create a new Play 2.x project
4. Run the project from Intellij 14 (open via localhost:9000 is successfully)
5. Run the default tests (ApplicationSpec, IntegrationSpec) won't run because of the error message below.

**Why test-classes won't be generated when I run the default tests?**

Is something wrong with my configurations (see http://prntscr.com/53nk41 and http://prntscr.com/53nkj7)?

Thanks for any advice!

**Error:**

```
Testing started at 18:31 ...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IntegrationSpec
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.loadClassOf(Classes.scala:206)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.loadClassOf(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$loadClassEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:197)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$loadClassEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:197)
org.specs2.control.Exceptions$class.trye(Exceptions.scala:92)
org.specs2.control.Exceptions$.trye(Exceptions.scala:108)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.loadClassEither(Classes.scala:197)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.loadClassEither(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:90)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObject(Classes.scala:70)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObject(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationOption$1.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationOption$1.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationOption(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecification(BaseSpecification.scala:94)
org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.createSpecification(ClassRunner.scala:64)
org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.start(ClassRunner.scala:35)
org.specs2.runner.NotifierRunner.start(NotifierRunner.scala:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.runSingleTest(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:92)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.main(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:68)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
can not create specification: IntegrationSpec
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ApplicationSpec
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.loadClassOf(Classes.scala:206)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.loadClassOf(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$loadClassEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:197)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$loadClassEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:197)
org.specs2.control.Exceptions$class.trye(Exceptions.scala:92)
org.specs2.control.Exceptions$.trye(Exceptions.scala:108)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.loadClassEither(Classes.scala:197)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.loadClassEither(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:90)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObject(Classes.scala:70)
org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObject(Classes.scala:213)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationOption$1.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationOption$1.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationOption(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecification(BaseSpecification.scala:94)
org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.createSpecification(ClassRunner.scala:64)
org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.start(ClassRunner.scala:35)
org.specs2.runner.NotifierRunner.start(NotifierRunner.scala:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.runSingleTest(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:92)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.main(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:68)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
can not create specification: ApplicationSpec
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Same here. Same IntelliJ, same error

Comment: @ChrisBeach do you have already a solution for that?

Comment: not yet I'm afraid. Still waiting to hear from others.

Comment: Has it ever worked for Intellij IDEA? Cause I'm a beginner with regard to Intellij... Please let me know if you find something out.

Comment: Believe this is now resolved. See answer below

Comment: Yes it is resolved :)

Comment: @Rdey, how did you fix it? A newer plugin version? Which one?

Comment: @PaulDraper I have just updated my scala plugin. For me it works with scala plugin version 1.2.1 and IntelliJ 14.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved in release 1.1.2 of the IntelliJ Scala plugin, as of 21st November:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=&updateId=17896

Comment: Scala support might not be all it can be (heck, even scalac doesn't support Scala that well), but I haven't found a better IDE for Scala.